# Pandas add column to df after group_by and value_counts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

```
import pandas as pd
group = ['A']*5 + ['B']*4 + ['C']*3
color = ['red', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'green', 'red'] * 2
df = pd.DataFrame({'group':group, 'color':color})
df
```

```
    group   color
0   A   red
1   A   red
2   A   green
3   A   blue
4   A   green
5   B   red
6   B   red
7   B   red
8   B   green
9   C   blue
10  C   green
11  C   red
```

What I want is to add new column to this dataframe which will show frequency of each color in a group (as a part of whole).
Values for this column can be obtained with following code:

```
df.groupby('group').color.value_counts(normalize=True)
```

```
group  color
A      green    0.400000
       red      0.400000
       blue     0.200000
B      red      0.750000
       green    0.250000
C      blue     0.333333
       green    0.333333
       red      0.333333
Name: color, dtype: float64
```

However I cannot figure out how to turn it into a column corresponding to original dataframe. I've tried

```
df['freq'] = df.groupby('group').color.transform('value_counts(normalize=True)') # error
```

which doesn't work.
Here is the output I am looking for:

```
    group   color   freq
0   A   red         0.4
1   A   red         0.4
2   A   green       0.4
3   A   blue        0.2
4   A   green       0.4
5   B   red         0.75
6   B   red         0.75
7   B   red         0.75
8   B   green       0.25
9   C   blue        0.33
10  C   green       0.33
11  C   red         0.33
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) counts on `group` and `color`:

```
counts = df.groupby('group')['color'].value_counts(normalize=True)
df = df.join(counts.rename('freq'), on=['group', 'color'])
```

```
   group  color      freq
0      A    red  0.400000
1      A    red  0.400000
2      A  green  0.400000
3      A   blue  0.200000
4      A  green  0.400000
5      B    red  0.750000
6      B    red  0.750000
7      B    red  0.750000
8      B  green  0.250000
9      C   blue  0.333333
10     C  green  0.333333
11     C    red  0.333333
```

---

Or calculate normalized value counts manually with counting `group` + `color` counts vs `group` counts via [`groupby transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['freq'] = (
        df.groupby(['group', 'color'])['color'].transform('count') /
        df.groupby('group')['group'].transform('count')
)
```

```
   group  color      freq
0      A    red  0.400000
1      A    red  0.400000
2      A  green  0.400000
3      A   blue  0.200000
4      A  green  0.400000
5      B    red  0.750000
6      B    red  0.750000
7      B    red  0.750000
8      B  green  0.250000
9      C   blue  0.333333
10     C  green  0.333333
11     C    red  0.333333
```

Answer (score 3):

Fix it by `MultiIndex` and `reindex`

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df[['group' , 'color']])
df['new'] = df.groupby('group').color.value_counts(normalize=True).reindex(idx).values
df
Out[115]: 
   group  color       new
0      A    red  0.400000
1      A    red  0.400000
2      A  green  0.400000
3      A   blue  0.200000
4      A  green  0.400000
5      B    red  0.750000
6      B    red  0.750000
7      B    red  0.750000
8      B  green  0.250000
9      C   blue  0.333333
10     C  green  0.333333
11     C    red  0.333333
```

Comment: Don't think you need to explicitly convert to a `MultiIndex`: `.reindex(df[["group", "color"]])` should work